# Release management: How to copy .exe file to a different location

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, release-management, ms-release-management

I am trying to find how to copy a file (.exe) from drop folder to a different folder.  The build number format on TFS build definition is like this:$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r) and for every build, it automatically creates a subfolder in the drop folder, for example Validation_20160725.1/ and the .exe file I need to copy to a different location is inside this folder named Validation_20160725.1/.  "Copy" is part of deployment so it is performed through release management.  However, every build creates a new folder with datetime.rev# to folder name.  Is there an easy way to use release management to copy the .exe file to a different location?  Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Release Management are you using? The old desktop client or the new web based client?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component within release management. Select "Builds with application" and specify the file name in path to package. In the deployment tab select XCopy deployer.

Add this component in your template and you are good to go